# Best stemming algorithm in NLTK, Python

Tags: python, nlp, nltk

I am trying to stem the word tokens I get after tokenizing the data using PorterStemmer but am getting incorrect results. Which stemming algorithm would be the best one to go with?

Code-

```
from nltk.stem import PorterStemmer

porter = PorterStemmer()
porter.stem("mobile")
```

Code Output-

```
mobil
```

Expected Output-

```
mobile
```

Answer (score 1):

You might be looking for lemmatization and not stemming. Check out https://www.guru99.com/stemming-lemmatization-python-nltk.html.

Stemming means the reduction to the root/base of the word. Lemmatization means the reduction to the non-flectional base form (e.g. infinitive for verbs).

The root of `"mobile"` is `"mobil"` because of words like `"mobility"`. The unchanged root/base does in this case not include the `e`.

Comment: I tried `WordNetLemmatizer` on the word "giving" and it returned "giving". But with `PorterStemmer` it was able to return "give".